# Matrix to create sheets and copy certain information

Tags: excel

I have a unit matrix that illustrates work items for an apartment complex. It expands to 5 floors and has more work items than just the kitchen scope. My end goal is to have a sheet for each unit, listing the specific items needed for that unit. It would be very helpful once construction begins.

I want to do 2 things. 1 - Create new sheets for each unit (C5:C124) using the template. 2 - Copy over the information based on what is marked with an "X"

I know how to create a macros that will create blank sheets from the number of units I have. I'm stuck on integrating the template.

Thank you for reading.

[Unit Scope Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6McM.png)

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLpvu.jpg)

Edit 1:
Here is my new code that can take a range of room#s and create new sheets from it. Now I would like to copy and paste the the row next the the according room# cell and paste in the appropriate sheet.

```
Sub CreateSheets()
 
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range


    On Error GoTo Errorhandling


'Creates popup box asking for the room numbers
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select cell range:", _
    Title:="Create sheets", _
    Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
 
    For Each cell In rng

'Check if cell is not empty
    If cell <> "" Then
 
'Insert worksheet and name the worksheet based on cell value
    Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets("Unit Types")


'Name new sheet based off two cells on Bid Summary List Cells (Bi and Di)
ActiveSheet.Name = "UNIT-" & cell
    
'This is where I think I should add the copy/paste lines... but I don't know how.
'Copy unit# row and paste in correct worksheet
    'Range("XX:XX").Copy Range("XX:XX")
    
    
    End If

'Continue with next cell in cell range
Next cell
 
'Go here if an error occurs
Errorhandling:
 
'Stop macro
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

The code to copy the template and rename it is easy enough to make. Start recording, do one manually, stop recording, then press Alt-F11 to see how it's done, then steal from that to make your own function.

I suspect you'll end up with something that looks *like*

```
Function NewSheet(nm as String) as Worksheet
  Dim template As Worksheet

  set template = ActiveWorkbook.sheets('template')
  set NewSheet = template.copy(ActiveWorkbook)
  NewSheet.name = nm // change the tab name
  NewSheet range('B1') = nm // add to the sheet as well
End Function
```

*(warning: syntax and method names might unintentionally be wrong, this is intended to give you a head start, not do it for you)*

and then you'll need to write a macro that loops through column C and calls your function. In this case you can ignore that `NewSheet` returns a new Worksheet object, but this way provides flexible code for future needs. Also, by isolating what you need to do to make a new worksheet as its own function that's called multiple times, It's easier to reason through and test, and the looping code that calls it is much easier to read as well.

Try searching for "Excel VBA looping examples" to get a head start on looping if you are unfamiliar.

Comment: Hi, so I know its been some time. Here is my code that was able to copy a range and create new sheets. Now I would like to copy the data range to the room# cell. Here is what I have so far...